# How to set for m2m-field different querysets for each inline object?

Tags: python, django, inlines

So I have a model that is shown in inline form.
That model have `ManyToManyField`.

Imagine that there are several inline-objects that are already created.

The problem is how to show different querysets of available objects in my m2m-field based on original inline-object.

One more time:)
I mean that in each inline-object must by m2m-field with different available variants.
Variants will of course include all that is actually set for this inline-object + they must include only variants that are not present at the moment anywhere else.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Question is very poorly written, so it's hard to be sure exactly what you're looking for, but my best guess is that you're want to limit the queryset for the `ManyToManyField` to items that are not assigned to anything else? If that's correct:

(*You also didn't post an example model, so I'll make one up to illustrate*)

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    my_m2m_field = models.ManyToManyField(OtherModel)
```

And, here's the code to limit the field based on that:

```
class SomeModelInlineAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyInlineAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['my_m2m_field'].queryset = OtherModel.objects.filter(somemodel__isnull=True)

class SomeModelInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SomeModel
    form = SomeModelInlineAdminForm
```